# (Just HTML) Failed to load image from both directory & link

Tags: html

I've tried to show an image, but it doesn't seem to load from the website or on my PC. The size of the image is 400 x 400 pixels.

The website I'm getting the image from is Twitter (by copying the link address of the image then the images address, getting the link from there)

The file is in the same directory as the code.

`<img src=”ImageofMyself.jpg” alt="Image of Myself">`

Comment: Use the proper quotes. You have `”`, but it should be `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use the proper quotes. You have ”, but it should be ". – yunzen

You can do this by using proper quotes. you should change `”` to `"`

```
<img src="ImageofMyself.jpg" alt="Image of Myself">
```